# Network is unreachable for hg clone

Tags: proxy, mercurial

Autoproxy was installed on my firefox,and every web can be browsed via socket5 proxy service after buying vps service.

```
apt-get install mercurial  #on my local pc
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/   /tmp/vim  #on my local pc
abort: error: Network is unreachable
```

https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ can be visited via autoproxy in Firefox.
How to build some kind of proxy service on my remote VPS to make the `hg clone` command to reach https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/?

Not all webs can be visited here, I have build a ladder to reach them via Firefox.

How to make another ladder on my VPS (on the remote PC) to make the `hg clone` command run on my local PC?

Every time I make the ladder with my VPS and Firefox this way:

1. To input ssh command in my local pc

   ```
   ssh -D 127.0.0.1:1080  -p 1234 root@44.44.44.44
   ```
2. Click the Autoproxy plugin into Global mode. It was set in good status in Socket 5 proxy.
3. Now i can visit what I want to visit.

How to write the `hg clone` command?

Comment: Vim is no longer on Google code, and hasn't been for a while. That repo hasn't been updated for six months.  [Use the GitHub repo](https://github.com/vim/vim). If you really want to keep using mercurial, then there's [a mirror at Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/vim-mirror/vim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use proxy for Mercurial you can prefix your command with `http_proxy`:

```
http_proxy=http://proxy-server:8080 hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg
```

Or configure in your `~/.hgrc` as:

```
[http_proxy]
host=proxy-host:port
user=username
passwd=password
```

Since you're using a SOCKS5 proxy, this is not yet supported by Mercurial (3.7.2 at time of writing), however there is [an extension](https://bitbucket.org/bugheisen/socks_proxy) for it based on the [patch](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2014-April/057871.html) below.

#### Extension

You can download a small extension for the Mercurial DVCS to enable the use of a SOCKS5 proxy: https://bitbucket.org/bugheisen/socks_proxy

So can configure your proxy in your `~/.hgrc` as:

```
[extensions]
socks_proxy = /path/to/socks_proxy.py

[socks_proxy]
host = localhost:9150
```

> To experiment with a SOCKS5 proxy you can use the -D option of SSH,
>   which creates such a proxy that runs over the SSH connection.
>   Alternatively you can run Tor, which also starts a SOCKS5 proxy
>   (probably either on port 9050 or port 9150).

#### Patch

The above extension is based on the original patch posted by Bug Heisen and you can apply by [downloading the source code of Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads) and applying this [patch](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2014-April/057871.html) based on the code below:

```
diff -r 12f161f08d74 -r 3f58227755ed mercurial/url.py
--- a/mercurial/url.py  Tue Apr 01 23:41:32 2014 -0700
+++ b/mercurial/url.py  Sun Apr 06 16:16:02 2014 +0200
@@ -63,6 +63,44 @@

 class proxyhandler(urllib2.ProxyHandler):
     def __init__(self, ui):
+
+        # First, check if a SOCKS5 proxy is set, using a line 'host = ...' in 
+        # the [socks_proxy] section of the config file.
+
+        proxyurl = ui.config("socks_proxy", "host")
+
+        if proxyurl:
+            idx = proxyurl.find(":")
+            if idx < 0:
+                raise util.Abort(_("host in socks_proxy should be "
+                                   "hostname:port"))
+
+            host = proxyurl[:idx]
+            portstr = proxyurl[idx+1:]
+            try:
+                port = int(portstr)
+            except ValueError:
+                raise util.Abort(_("Cannot interpret '%s' in the socks_proxy "
+                                   "host line as an integer port number") 
+                                   % portstr)
+
+            if port <= 0 or port > 65535:
+                raise util.Abort(_("Port number in socks_proxy host line "
+                                   "must lie between 1 and 65535, but is "
+                                   "%d") % port)
+
+            ui.note("Setting SOCKS5 proxy to %s:%d\n" % (host, port))
+                    
+            try:
+                import socks
+                socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, host, port)
+                socket.socket = socks.socksocket
+            except ImportError:
+                raise util.Abort(_("The SocksiPy socks module is needed for "
+                                   "SOCKS support"))
+
+        # Then check for a http/https proxy
+        
         proxyurl = ui.config("http_proxy", "host") or os.getenv('http_proxy')
         # XXX proxyauthinfo = None
```

then in your `~/.hgrc` use `socks_proxy` instead of `http_proxy` (as shown above).

Original notes regarding this patch:

> This patch adds support for a SOCKS5 proxy, using the 'socks' module
>   from the SocksiPy projects (needs to be installed separately). Because
>   it is the 'proxyhandler' function that is modified, it will only work
>   for HTTP/HTTPS protocols. For the SSH protocol, using a SOCKS proxy
>   can easily be done outside of Mercurial, by specifying the
>   `ProxyCommand` option.
>
> The patch has the SOCKS5 version hardcoded in it, but the `socks`
>   module should support other versions as well. So other SOCKS versions
>   are possible in the same way, but the code would require modification
>   to support them.
>
> For testing purposes, it's good to know that SSH can create a SOCKS5
>   proxy using the `-D` command line flag. Using Tor also generates such
>   a proxy, typically either on port 9050 or 9150.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to start with configuring the proxy settings for your local mercurial instance. Check `hg help config` and look for proxy there.

```
"http_proxy"
------------

Used to access web-based Mercurial repositories through a HTTP proxy.

"host"
    Host name and (optional) port of the proxy server, for example
    "myproxy:8000".

"no"
    Optional. Comma-separated list of host names that should bypass the
    proxy.

"passwd"
    Optional. Password zur Authentifikation mit einem Proxy-Server.

"user"
    Optional. User name to authenticate with at the proxy server.

"always"
    Optional. Always use the proxy, even for localhost and any entries in
    "http_proxy.no". (default: False)
```